# Is recepted a word?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, is-it-a-word

I have been saying this for years, I think. I also thought I had heard it used before. However, today I used it in a sentence, and my spell checker under lined it.

The sentence(fragment) I wrote was:

"and this idea was recepted fairly well."

I did a Google search and found "recept" is a word:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recept

which does sort of align with my intent of usage.

Then there is "receptacle": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/receptacle

and "reception": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reception

I also found "receipted" as a suggestion that may sort of correlate with my usage.

Has anyone else ever used, or heard "recepted"?

Oh, and PS, my voice to text recognized and wrote the word as such.

Comment: Were you looking for _received_? Ideas are normally received, unless you mean this idea of yours was turned into a mental image formed by repeated exposure, which sounds… fishy.

Comment: https://whichiscorrect.com/received-or-recepted/

Comment: http://www.spellcheck.net/misspelled-words/recepted

Comment: https://www.spellchecker.net/misspellings/recepted

Comment: @Justin Thank you for the links. I think the closest replacement would be "received" but, like I say, I am pretty sure I have always used this word, and so "recepted" is actually what I meant. I think of it as sort of in between "recept" and "receptacle" with a hint of "reception". I mean, the idea was received, understood, taken in, thought about, and so it was "recepted" well. I don't know, I just think I have been saying this for years. Maybe it needs to be a word...

Comment: Think: received and accepted...

Comment: I see all the variations of "received" are spelled similarly. I guess it's just one of those weird situations in English. "Recepted" would make more sense than "received" when you think about "receptively", "receptive", "receptiveness", "reception", and "receptacle". But then, English is like,"hey, put an 'i' in there and change that 'pt' to a 'v', because reasons."

Comment: Obviously if you've been saying it for years, it has to be a word. What else could it be, some sort of indigestion-triggered belly-fart? :)

Comment: If I see "and this idea was recepted fairly well", I would guess that the speaker was not a native speaker of English.

Comment: @takintoolong Because French, actually. These are all French loan words. They’re not really regular (to the extent that a verb and a noun can be ‘regular’) in French either, but there at least they’re the outcome of regular Latin words undergoing regular sound changes. In Latin, the verb is _recipere_ and its past participle is (regularly) _receptus_. On its way to French, intervocalic /p/ became /b/, then /v/, and /pt/ became /tt/; so _recipe-_ > _recive-_ (Fr. _recevoir_), but _recept-_ > _recett-_. The spelling of _rece(i)pt_ was changed back to match the etymology.

Comment: For those voting to close as off-topic/gen ref, the point is that the OP _did_ do research and could find nothing. 'recepted' is a common mistake but if you don't know, you don't know, and you don't understand why others think it is wrong. It's a reasonable thing to ask about (even though it is a very good example of 'not a word').

Comment: I'm familiar with receptacles and receipts. I have never encountered the words 'recept' or 'recepted'

Answer (score 16):

If you wish to use *recept* as a verb, you’re a bit late to the party:

> Where it is said, that whosoever shall *recept* the thing stoln willingly and knowingly, he shall be punished as the principal thief; and from this it may be concluded, that *recept* with us, is properly, when the thing stoln is *recepted*, and not when the stealer without the theft is *receipted*; for to as the *recepting* of the thief, it appears only to be punishable, when letters of intercommuning are published, prohibiting all the leidges *to recept* or fortifie a malefactor, … — Sir George Mackenzie, *The Laws and Customes of Scotland*, 1678. EEBO

This usage survived into the 19th c., but today is obsolete: *receive* is the verb you want. Just as you might *conceive* of something and produce a *concept*, you do not **concept* a better mousetrap.

Even the noun has undergone changes over the years:

> We should at the ministracion and *recept* of the sacrament, haue good natural bread: but in stede thereof, we haue printed waifers, and suche starched stuffe, as is not pure &; perfecte bread, nor lyke vnto that whych was vsed in the eating of the Lordes holy supper at the first. — John Ponet, *Humble and Unfained Confession*, 1554. EEBO
>
> Army Medical Department, 7 Nov. 1829.
>   Sir — I have the honour to acknowledge the [*recept*](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/32075902?searchTerm=recept) of your note of the 30th October … — *Sydney Monitor*, 13 Aug. 1831.
>
> We have just been shown a [*recept*](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=SJO18580906.2.58&txq=%22a+recept+for%22) for curing chronic, sore eyes, which is the result of a long and close study of a very distinguished physician lately from Scotland. — *Daily Illinois State Journal* (Springfield IL), 6 Sept. 1858.

Today, it would be *reception* of the Sacrament, *receipt* of a letter, and a *prescription* for curing sore eyes. Since the 1580s, the earlier alternative to *recept* was *[recipe](https://www.etymonline.com/word/recipe#etymonline_v_7383)*, from Middle French *récipé*, from Latin *recipe*, ‘take!’, surviving today only in the abbreviation ℞ at a pharmacy.

Comment: "receipt" is also an old form of "recipe" (instructions for cooking) - particularly in American English.

Comment: @MartinBonner: A number of European languages have borrowed this word. In a prescription for antibiotics and a recipe for a cake the word is still _Rezept_.

Comment: I was going to make exactly that point about German!

Comment: I learned a thing today. I did not know what the ℞ meant (and hadn't been important enough to go find out).

Comment: Thank you for this information, it is interesting. But, is the answer yes? It sounds like it is a word, just happens to be a word not used anymore? Except by me of course.

Comment: @takintoolong: “obsolete” means the word is no longer part of the living language. Since you are not living in late 17th c. Scotland, stick with _receive_.